# Rotate <svg> with one line of XML

Tags: svg

Is there a way to rotate an SVG graphic with just one line of code?
Is making a group or layer for all elements the best way?

Comment: How is the <svg> displayed? Via an <object> tag or inline in html or standalone?

Comment: I need a solution that works also standalone.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As the `transform` attribute is not allowed on the document element, you'll need a `<g>` element that contains everything you want to rotate.

But if the SVG is embedded inside HTML, you could use CSS transforms:

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" style="transform:rotate(45deg)" width="10" height="10">
  <rect width="10" height="10"/>
</svg>
```

Unfortunately, right now you still need vendor prefixes, like `-webkit-transform`. In Firefox, it already works without prefix.